# How to forward Redis Pub/Sub messages to SignalR 2 in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a Redis server to which a service publishes messages to a certain channel. Now, I would like to use the latest SignalR 2 bits (1.0.0-alpha2-final at the time of writing) for .NET Core in another application to just push/forward messages sent to that particular channel to the client (the browser in my case).

I added the following NuGet packages to my ASP.NET Core project...

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.0.0-alpha2-final" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Redis" Version="1.0.0-alpha2-final" />
```

...and configured SignalR services like:

```
services.AddSignalRCore().AddRedis(options =>
{
    options.Factory = writer =>
    {
        string host = ...;
        int.TryParse(this.Configuration["<port>"], out int port);
        var configuration = new ConfigurationOptions
        {
            EndPoints = { {host, port} },
            Password = this.Configuration["<secret>"],
        };

        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configuration, writer);
    };
});
```

Since there´s no hub (I actually don´t know if I need one), I have no idea how the JavaScript client can subscribe. Besides that it is not the application itself that pushes the messages, it´s another application that publishes messages to Redis via `PUBLISH`. Sending messages to the application via an HTTP request instead is not an option because that would be to slow; this is a (near to) real-time scenario...

I would like to know if it is possible to forward Redis Pub/Sub communication to SignalR (out of the box), or if I need to utilize the StackExchange client and connect it to a hub manually.

Comment: You have to subscribe to redis channel from your application and forward all messages to all connected signalr clients.

Comment: @Evk: how? is there any example of that?

Comment: @Div there are two separate message channels - Redis (server-side), and SignlalR (bus between client and server). Then, some application on server wants to send message to client. It cannot do this directly, so it should send message to another server application - asp.net service. Asp.net service receives this message and then forwards it via SinglalR to the respective client. So you just need to find an example of how to publish and subscribe to Redis, and separately how to publish and subscribe to SignalR, of which I think there are plenty over internet.

Comment: @Evk, Thanks for your detailed answer! I have further doubts, for example, how to subscribe Redis channel using javascript as we're not using node js. Anyway, will ask a new question and post a link here, so you can have clear picture of the problem.